# unable to transform dataflow to yml on minifi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have *Minifi* on a Windows machine. However, I am unable to use the

config.bat transform command.

I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   Files\minifi-0.5.0-bin\minifi-toolkit-0.5.0\bin..\lib*

Im not sure what it means. Thank you